# Sequenciado de nomes

Tags: javascript, html5

Estou tentando montar um javascript que escreva de modo sequenciado uma frase dentro da minha div, e após alguns segundos ele substitua o texto por um outro pre programado, já tentei fazer com for, temporizador e ainda não conseguir, ao invés de aguardar a primeira mensagem ser escrita para escrever a segunda ele simplesmente escreve ambas ao mesmo tempo.

```js
var div = document.getElementById('log');
var texto = ['Hoje está um lindo dia!','Hoje não está um lindo dia!','Hoje o dia estar horrivel'];

function escrever(str, el) {
    var char = str.split('').reverse();
    var typer = setInterval(function () {
        if (!char.length) return clearInterval(typer);
        var next = char.pop();
        el.innerHTML += next;
    }, 100);
}
 setTimeout(escrever(texto[0], div),5000);
 setTimeout(escrever(texto[1], div),5000);
```

```html
<div id="log"></div>
```

Comment: Mas vc ta escrevendo as duas coisas, ao mesmo tempo, com mesmo timeout...

Comment: Ah, além do fato de que o innerhtml vai adicionar o conteúdo desejado, nao substituir o conteúdo todo, que me parece ser seu objetivo.

Comment: Você colocou o timeout igual, Altera por exemplo setTimeout(escrever(texto[0], div),1000); e no segundo deixa os 5000, Em 1 seg executará 1 e depois de 4 segundos o outro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No setTimeout chame o escrever dentro da function como no exemplo abaixo e a primeira chama não precisa de timeout, Logo chamará diretamente ela, e após 3 segundos chamará o segundo método:

```js
var div = document.getElementById('log');
var texto = ['Hoje está um lindo dia!','Hoje não está um lindo dia!','Hoje o dia estar horrivel'];

function escrever(str, el) {
    var char = str.split('').reverse();
    var typer = setInterval(function () {
        if (!char.length) return clearInterval(typer);
        var next = char.pop();
        el.innerHTML += next;
    }, 100);
}
escrever(texto[0], div);
setTimeout(function(){ escrever(texto[1], div)}, 3000);
```

```html
<div id="log"></div>
```